# End FFMPEG execution when RTMP input is closed

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, process

I have an RTMP arut server inside which I call a python script to run an FFMPEG command and create HLS packaging.

Problem is that when I stop the RTMP stream, FFMPEG still run processes in background.

FFMPEG string is like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -v verbose -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/testlive  -rw_timeout 500 -http_persistent 1 -method PUT -http_user_agent test -f hls -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags discont_start+delete_segments  -vf "scale=426:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 24 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event -preset veryfast  -b:v 300k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k  -b:a 128k -vcodec libx264 -hls_segment_filename http://mystream/123/v1/testlive/0_%03d.ts  http://mystream/123/v1/testlive/index.m3u8
```

Comment: Problem is that I can't get error from FFMPEG when input RTMP stream end, so FFMPEG remain in "listem mode" for input and never end.

Comment: Hi @tidpe were you able to do this? if yes can you please help to achieve same?

Comment: Actually not, I've done a "workaround" that end process when files inside streaming directory are not written for X time.

Answer (score 1):

The RTMP server should send an `NetStream.Play.Stop` event to subscribers (or disconnect them) to signal end of stream. If you are using the nginx rtmp module, look at the `play_restart` or `idle_streams` directives.